# How to load images after localisation of UIImage (I am changing language within the application)

Tags: ios, localization, uiimage, xcode5

I following the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios for implementing  UIImage localisation.This work perfectly when does change phone language in Phone settings .But I want to change Language within the application.After that this tutorial is not working.

I used the following code to change the curent langaugae .

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"]; 
[DataManager shared].languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

I used the normal ways to load your images ([UIImage imageNamed:@xyz.png"])..What i am Missing..

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code in question instead of commenting code.